# invalid cursor state while using table valued parameter and ODBC

Tags: c++, sql-server, sql-server-2012, odbc

I would like to create Table Valued Parameter in MSSQL Server using ODBC and c++. Such a SQL Code works fine in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @T1 as TABLE
(
 PK INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
 Wert CHAR(20),
 Name CHAR(20)
 )
 INSERT INTO @T1(Wert,Name) VALUES ('123','Babio') 
 INSERT INTO @T1(Wert,Name) VALUES ('214','Martin') 
 INSERT INTO @T1(Wert,Name) VALUES ('236','Karo') 

 select * FROM @T1 where  Wert=123
```

I have written this block of code in c++ to send this SQL Code to SQL Server using ODBC:

```
int main()
{
    SQLHENV henv=SQL_NULL_HENV;
    SQLHDBC hdbc=SQL_NULL_HDBC;
    SQLHSTMT hstmt=SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
    SQLRETURN rc;


   SQLCHAR Statement[] = "DECLARE @T1 as TABLE (PK INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, Wert CHAR(20), Name CHAR(20)) INSERT INTO @T1(Wert,Name) VALUES ('123','Babak')  INSERT INTO @T1(Wert,Name) VALUES ('214','Martin') INSERT INTO @T1(Wert,Name) VALUES ('236','Karo')  select Name FROM @T1 Where Wert=123" ;


   SQLWCHAR dsn[30] = L"mssqltest"; //Name DNS
   SQLWCHAR user[10] = L"di_test";
   SQLWCHAR pass[10] = L"di_test";

   SQLCHAR retValFName[256];
   SQLCHAR retValLName[256];
   SQLINTEGER cbLName,cbFName;

   rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);  
   rc= SQLSetEnvAttr(henv,SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,(void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3,0);
   rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);  
   rc = SQLConnectW(hdbc, (SQLWCHAR *)dsn, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR *) user, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR *) pass, SQL_NTS); 
   rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hdbc,&hstmt);
   rc = SQLPrepareA(hstmt, (SQLCHAR *)Statement, SQL_NTS);
   rc = SQLExecute(hstmt);

   if(rc==SQL_SUCCESS)
   {
   while(true)
        {
          rc=SQLFetch(hstmt); // In this line rc=-1
          if(rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc==SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
          {
             SQLGetData(hstmt,1,SQL_C_CHAR,retValFName,256, &cbLName);
             std::cout << retValFName <<"   "<< std::endl;
             system("pause");
          }
          else
          {
              break;
          }
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If I check the error, I see this error which says:

> Invalid Cursor state

How could be my code changes to run this code to create and make a query on Table Valued Parameter in SQL?

Comment: What is the return value of the call to SQLPrepare()? And is the data actually inserted into the table - if you check using some other tool?

Comment: it returns 0. I can run this T-SQL in SQL Server management studio